# Switch Payment Profiles on Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I am based in India and my account has a billing address of USA. (this was long ago) I have made another profile which has a billing address of India, and I need to use the Direct Carrier Billing payment method but my Play Store is still showing me my USA profile.

How do I change my Payments Profile on the Play Store app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now change this in the `Google Play` app under:

> Menu > Account > Preferences > Country and profiles

If you have more than one profile - they should be here.

In case if you are stuck with a single `business` profile - signing up for YouTube premium creates an `individual` profile.

Comment: This no longer seems to be the case...

Answer (score 2):

Go to payments.google.com and change your settings there. You are not allowed to have payment methods from multiple countries, so you'll have to remove your old info and keep only the new one. Make sure you clear data and cache of your playstore to force it to update new info after you make the changes.

Comment: What about Play store credit in the currency of the previous profile?

Comment: @simbabque it won't convert. Your credit in old profile stays as is. The new profile starts as a new account.